# What is the best way to update Node_Modules that are outdated?

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

[image]

Is there a way to update or remove deprecated packages using `npm` or `yarn`?

Also is there a way I can automate it?

Comment: I thought **npm audit** does that?

Comment: No npm audit only checks for vulnerabilities but it does not remove deprecated modules

Comment: but **npm audit fix** will update vulnerabilities.   Removing deprecated modules will crash old code. No?

Comment: It could but do you know how to remove them?

Comment: npm uninstall (package name) ?

Comment: Npm uninstall did not work because the deprecated packages are not in package.json file

Comment: So it's not installed "locally"... But globally?

Comment: Yes - globally.

Comment: These are indirect dependencies. It is up to their maintainer to update them.